# How can I pass multiple ids in getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big question, how can I optimize this in just one script?

This causes all three elements to be enable or disabled depending of the checkbox.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('active_0').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('gender_0').disabled = this.checked;
        document.getElementById('size_0').disabled = this.checked;
        document.getElementById('q_0').disabled = this.checked;
    };
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('active_0').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('gender_0').disabled = !this.checked;
        document.getElementById('size_0').disabled = !this.checked;
        document.getElementById('q_0').disabled = !this.checked;
    };
</script>

--- this script repeats 6 times from active_0 to active_5---

 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('active_5').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('gender_5').disabled = this.checked;
        document.getElementById('size_5').disabled = this.checked;
        document.getElementById('q_5').disabled = this.checked;
    };
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('active_5').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('gender_5').disabled = !this.checked;
        document.getElementById('size_5').disabled = !this.checked;
        document.getElementById('q_5').disabled = !this.checked;
    };
</script>
```

thx to @Nidhin Joseph

this is my new script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='active_']");

    for (const element of elements) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            let index = this.id.split('_')[1];

            document.getElementById(`gender_${index}`).disabled = this.checked;
            document.getElementById(`size_${index}`).disabled = this.checked;
            document.getElementById(`q_${index}`).disabled = this.checked;

            document.getElementById(`gender_${index}`).disabled = !this.checked;
            document.getElementById(`size_${index}`).disabled = !this.checked;
            document.getElementById(`q_${index}`).disabled = !this.checked;     
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and then attach click events to all divs with id matching `active_*`. In the click event, you can use the `split` method to extract the number part and then use to access your dom elements.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='active_']");

for (const element of elements) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let index = this.id.split('_')[1];
    console.log(`gender_${index}`, `size_${index}`, `q_${index}`);
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id='active_0'>a</div>
<div id='active_1'>b</div>
<div id='active_2'>c</div>
<div id='active_3'>d</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is meant to be used when you want to select one element with a particular.

For your use case you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
function select(){
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#a,#b,#c,#d")
  console.log(elements)
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>a</div>
<div id='b'>b</div>
<div id='c'>c</div>
<div id='d'>d</div>

<button onclick="select()">Select by id's</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

put a comma (,) for every selector.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('#active_5, #active_4, #active_3, #active_2, #active1').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('gender_5').disabled = this.checked;
        document.getElementById('size_5').disabled = this.checked;
        document.getElementById('q_5').disabled = this.checked;
    };
</script>
```

and don't forget to add (#) sign before the selector hope this helps you